# How to maintain two git repositories that share (most of) a file?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have a git repository that I used to maintain all the .tex files, figures, and code corresponding to a research article. Actually, I have several articles, one repository per article. Now I am working on my dissertation which has its own git repository, and several of the chapters will be based on previous research, i.e. the content in the article repositories.

How can I copy the relevant files from the article git repository to the dissertation repository so that I can sync selected commits between the two repositories?

For example, I make a commit to the dissertation that changes several lines of a .tex file to make the output match the required formatting for my dissertation. These changes should never be reflected in the article repository. However, I make a second commit that fixes a typo in a different section of the .tex file. The changes from the second commit, *and only these changes* should be synced to the article repository. One of my co-authors from the article expands one of the sections in the .tex file in the article repository. I want to pull these changes, (but only the changes from that commit, not overwriting other sections) over to the dissertation repository.

What is the simplest way to update one repository with select changes from another repository, given that some sections of the files between the two repositories may start to diverge considerably?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is most probably git submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules. this will allow you to share a repo pegged to a specific version of a file.

so ideally you will have three repos: dissertation, article and shared. then you will pull in shared to other two repos as a submodule.

**edit:**
now that i think of it again, i think you might be able solve this issue by simply maintaining multiple branches. one for dissertation and one for article. the files you need to change: create another branch, make changes. then only merge it to the branch or branches you want to merge the changes to. i think learning about the git flow workflow might help you think clearly: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/